# Set Minimum Zoom for View in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

How can I set a minimum zoom level for a view in OpenLayers 3?

```
map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [imageLayer, vectorLayer],
    renderer: 'canvas',
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View2D({
        projection: pixelProjection,
        center: ol.extent.getCenter(pixelProjection.getExtent()),
        extent: pixelProjection.getExtent(),
        zoom: 3.5,
        maxZoom: 4, // there is option for maxZoom, but no minZoom?
    })
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the API : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.View.html

Yes there is minZoom

```
map = new ol.Map({
layers: [imageLayer, vectorLayer],
renderer: 'canvas',
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View2D({
    projection: pixelProjection,
    center: ol.extent.getCenter(pixelProjection.getExtent()),
    extent: pixelProjection.getExtent(),
    zoom: 3.5,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 4
})
});
```